# Caffe error when installing through anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, caffe, pycaffe

I'm struggling to just install and import Caffe on my windows 10's Anaconda. I really don't know why such a well-known deep-learning package is that hard to just install!

First, I tried to install it. With huge difficulties, I did the following and at last, apparently, the installation was successful:

```
conda create -n caffe python=3.7
// activate the environment REM Depending on your conda version you may have to use activate Caffe

conda activate caffe
// add the anaconda channel to resolve all dependencies

conda config --add channels anaconda
// Install caffe with cuda support or install caffe-cpu if you do not want CUDA support

conda install caffe-cpu -c willyd
```

And now, just trying to import caffe, I get this error:

```
>>> import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\caffe\lib\site-packages\caffe\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\caffe\lib\site-packages\caffe\pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What should I do? How to fix it?